# How to wrap an div with another div - jQuery Wrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

Full Edit:

How can I wrap an jquery div with another div?

Sample:
There is

```
        this.vpath = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'rollbar-path-vertical'
    });
```

inside of one jquery script...

Now I tried to use this:

```
$('.rollbar-path-vertical').wrapAll('<div class="path-fix" />');
```

To make that .rollbar-path-vertical inside of another div named .path-fix... What am i doing wrong? I am going crazy... Thanks for your nerves and time.

CSS:

```
    .path-fix {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
}

.rollbar-path-vertical {
    right: 5px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 8px -5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the CSS to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Try removing position absolute from **.path-fix** And see if that gets you any closer.

```
.path-fix {
    width:15px;
}
```

Comment: Yes man... Now my div appears and wrapped up jquery scroll ... but I used absolute cause I want to position fixed part so it doesnt move on zooming or higher res... I will play arround, hope I can make it. Thanks.